# Issue trying to read enough bytes from a binary file

Tags: c, sockets, binary, fwrite

I am currently working on a project where I send from a client to a server a binary file.

The main problem I am facing right now is that when I send using a payload of size 1400 (`char[1400]`) at the end of the file it just reads more instead of just the size it sends me and I think it reads some random memory zones.The problem with this is that it kind of ruins the rest of the program for me

Here is what I tried so far

```
   #define MSGSIZE      1400
  #define COUNT     100

  typedef struct {
  int len;
  char payload[MSGSIZE];
  } msg;

   int rest = size % MSGSIZE; 

   int length_final = 0;
        if(rest % sizeof(char) != 0){
            length_final = rest / sizeof(char) + 1;

        }
        else{
            length_final = rest / sizeof(char);
        }



        while(smth<size){
            res = recv_message(&r);
            if(((count = fwrite(r.payload,1,MSGSIZE,file1))+smth)<size){

            sprintf(r.payload,"ACK");
            r.len = 4;

            res = send_message(&r);
            if (res < 0) {
                perror("[RECEIVER] Send ACK error. Exiting.\n");
                return -1;
            }
            else{
                if(smth<size){
                    smth +=count;

                }else{
                    break;
                }

            }   
            }
            else{

                count = fwrite(r.payload,1,length_final,file1);
                sprintf(r.payload,"ACK");
            r.len = 4;

            res = send_message(&r);
            smth +=count;
            }
        }
```

And it still doesn't work.Any ideas what I am doing wrong this far?

Ref file contains on it's last line[1651]:
      `706f 7274 00`

And my output file contains on 1651 :
       `706f 7274 0074 7566 662e 6300 5f5f 4a43` ,also my file prints 100 more random lines

PS:I am receiving chunks of bytes with each recv_message

Comment: Why your code contains sizeof(char) expressions? sizeof(char) is by definition always 1.

Comment: It's impossible to see how the `while` loop is behaving since you don't include anything about `ceva`, `size`, `smth` or `rest`. What is clear, when the superfluous `sizeof(char)` is removed the first few lines condense to: `int length_final = 0; if(rest) length_final = rest + 1;` so are you correctly setting `length_final`?

Comment: @WeatherVane I edited the code with the correct variable names and with the declaration of ceva

Comment: @juhist I am suppossed to read bytes,that is why i divided it with the sizeof(char)

Comment: But `sizeof(char)` is always 1, so the division by `sizeof(char)` has no effect.

Comment: oh.ok.I get it.I did that because when i return the size of the file it returns the size in bits,right?

Answer (score 1):

It is not easy to see exactly what you are trying to do, but something simplified along these lines might work. Specifically, instead of filing the whole buffer memory, only the length indicated in its `struct` is written.

```
#define MSGSIZE 1400

typedef struct {
    int len;
    char payload[MSGSIZE];
} msg;

int process_msg(int size) {
    msg ack = {4, "ACK"}, r = {0};
    int res, count;

    while(size > 0){
        res = recv_message(&r);
        if (res < 0) {
            perror("Receiver error. Exiting.\n");
            return -1;
        }
        if (r.len > 0) {
            count = fwrite(r.payload, 1, r.len, file1);
            if (count != r.len) {
                perror("Failed to write to file. Exiting.\n");
                return -1;
            }
        }
        res = send_message(&ack);
        if (res < 0) {
            perror("Failed to send ACK message. Exiting.\n");
            return -1;
        }
        size -= r.len;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be the following:

```
res = recv_message(&r);
if(((count = fwrite(r.payload,1,MSGSIZE,file1))+smth)<size){
```

In this, you receive the message and then write `MSGSIZE` worth of data. You seem to ignore the correct length of the read data. You didn't provide the definition of `recv_message()`, so I can't say where it returns the data length but perhaps the `r` structure has somewhere a field that contains the data length or perhaps `res` is the data length.

Comment: ,I added the definition of the structure r is

Comment: Well, then `r.len` seems to contain the message size so why not use that instead of `MSGSIZE`?

Comment: fwrite needs to know how many objects of the size 1 bytes needs to read,I simply say read MSGSIZE objects of that type

Comment: No, `fwrite` writes data, it does not read data. You say to write `MSGSIZE` objects, even though you may not have that many objects.

Comment: it writes data,sorry for the mistake.that is the issue I want to fix.How can I say:"just write enough objects"

Comment: if i replace the `length_final` with `rest` it does the same thing

Comment: Following the recent inclusion of the `struct` definition, should `fwrite(..., MSGSIZE, ...)` be `fwrite(..., r.len, ...)`?

Comment: @Weather Vane: No, as it is an example of how not to do things, not an example of how to do things. I just copied the problem part from the original source code and didn't modify it.

Comment: @juhist the comment was aimed at OP as a follow up to your answer, since he is writing `r.payload`.

Comment: let's say  @WeatherVane 's solution worked ,the follow up problem is that now it kind of wrecks a main buffer

Comment: Which main buffer, and why? Because `r.len` is larger than the buffer? Shouldn't you be using `r.len` as the actual size of `r.payload`? It is still very unclear what `size` and `smth` are doing since they have been neither declared nor initialised.

Comment: @WeatherVane I am sorry for the last comment.your answer was correct.Can you explain in a post[for everyone to see] why wast that?